# Equality of Two Series Expansions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to show the function 
\begin{equation}
f(x)=x^{-m} e^x\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^{m+n}e^{-x})
\end{equation}
is equal to the infinite series
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \frac{(m+n)!}{m!} \sum_{p=0}^n \frac{(-n)_p}{(m+1)_p p!}x^p.
\end{equation}
where $(a)_p = a(a+1)\dots(a+p-1)$. I can make it easier by rewriting the second version as
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \frac{(m+n)!}{m!} \sum_{p=0}^n \frac{(-n)_p}{(m+1)_p p!}x^p \\
&= \frac{(m+n)!}{m!} \sum_{p=0}^n \frac{(-n)(1-n)\dots(p-1-n)}{(m+1)(m+2)\dots(m+p) p!}x^p \\
&= \frac{(m+n)!}{m!} \sum_{p=0}^n \frac{n(n-1)\dots(n-p+1)}{(m+1)(m+2)\dots(m+p) p!}(-1)^p x^p \\
&= (m+n)! \sum_{p=0}^n \frac{n(n-1)\dots(n-p+1)}{p! p!}(-1)^p x^p \\
&= (m+n)! \sum_{p=0}^n \frac{n!}{p!(n-p)! p!}(-1)^p x^p.
\end{align}
But when I expand the first I get
\begin{align}
f(x) &= x^{-m} e^x\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^{m+n}e^{-x}) \\
&= x^{-m} e^x \sum_{p=0}^n {n \choose p} \frac{d^{n-p}}{dx^{n-p}}(x^{m+n})(\frac{d^p}{dx^p}e^{-x})  \\
&= x^{-m} e^x \sum_{p=0}^n  \frac{n!}{p!(n-p)!} (m+n)(m+n-1)\dots
(m+n-(n-p+1)) x^{m+n-n+p}(-1)^pe^{-x} \\
&= \sum_{p=0}^n  \frac{n!}{p!(n-p)!} (m+n)(m+n-1)\dots
(m+p-1)) x^p (-1)^p
\end{align}
i get stuck and when I expand a different way
\begin{align}
f(x) &= x^{-m} e^x\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^{m+n}e^{-x}) \\
&= x^{-m} e^x \sum_{p=0}^n {n \choose p} \frac{d^p}{dx^p}(x^{m+n})(\frac{d^{n-p}}{dx^{n-p}}e^{-x})  \\
&= x^{-m} e^x \sum_{p=0}^n  \frac{n!}{p!(n-p)!} (m+n)(m+n-1)\dots(m+n-p+1) x^{m+n-p}(-1)^{n-p} e^{-x} \\
&= \sum_{p=0}^n  \frac{n!}{p!(n-p)!} \frac{(m+n)!}{(m+n-p)!} x^{p}(-1)^{n-p} \\
&= (m+n)! \sum_{p=0}^n  \frac{n!}{p!(n-p)!} \frac{1}{(m+n-p)!} (-1)^{n-p} x^{p} \\
&= (m+n)! \sum_{p=0}^n  \frac{n(n-1) \dots (n - p + 1) (n-p)!}{p!(n-p)!} \frac{1}{(m+n-p)!} (-1)^{n-p} x^{p} \\
&= (m+n)! \sum_{p=0}^n  \frac{(-n)(1-n) \dots (p-1-n)}{p!} \frac{1}{(m+n-p)!} (-1)^{n} x^{p}
\end{align}
I get stuck again. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When expanding the sum you use $m! (m+1) \cdots (m+p) = p!$ instead of $m! (m+1) \cdots (m+p) = (m+p)!$ at one point. With this adjustment you will find the correct result
$$ f(x) = (m+n)! \sum \limits_{p=0}^n \frac{n!}{p!(n-p)!(m+p)!} (-1)^p x^p \, . $$

In the evaluation of the Rodrigues formula you should replace every $i$ by a $p$. In your first try there is just a small mistake: you should have
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}^{n-p}}{\mathrm{d}x^{n-p}} x^{m+n} = (m+n) \cdots (m+n - (n-p) \color{red}{+1}) x^{m+p} = \frac{(m+n)!}{(m+p)!} x^{m+p} \, . $$
Then the final results agree and you are done.

As for your second try, I do not know what 
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}^p}{\mathrm{d} x^{n-p}}$$
is supposed to mean, but you can simply take the first approach anyway.